# Сермяжная правда

Tags: фразеология

По поводу правды в русском языке фразеологизмов много. Например, есть правда подноготная и подлинная - эти слова происходят от видов пыток. А еще есть сермяжная правда. Это, как я понимаю, правда, скажем так, не прикрытая внешним лоском.
А почему она именно сермяжная? Насколько я помню, сермяга - это вид грубой ткани, так?

Answer (score 3):

Сермяжная правда - глубокая народная мудрость, выстраданная временем (из словаря крылатых выражений).

Также иносказательно: 1. Истина; правда; настоящие мотивы действий, истинная подоплека событий и пр. (ирон.). 2. Прописная истина, выдаваемая за глубокую народную мудрость (ирон.).

Сермяжный - одетый в сермягу, крестьянскую одежду из грубого некрашеного домотканого сукна.Ключевым словом, как мне кажется, является определение "некрашеный" - ничем не прикрашенный, истинный.

Из романа «Золотой теленок» (1931) советских писателей Ильи Ильфа (1897—1937) и Евгения Петрова (1903—1942). Диалог Остапа Бендера с Васисуалием Лоханкиным (гл. 13):

«Может быть, так надо. Может быть, именно в этом великая сермяжная правда. 
— Сермяжная? — задумчиво повторил Бендер. — Она же посконная, домотканая и кондовая? Так, так».

Answer (score -2):

сермяжная правда - глубокая народная мудрость, выстраданная временем - иносказательно, истина, правда; прописная истина, выдаваемая за глубокую народную мудрость <-

sermon [сермон] (англ.) - проповедь; sermonem [сермонем] (лат.) - речь, дискурс.